# MySQL Workbench Safety

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm a little (very) paranoid. I work with workbench for my own projects as well as for work. One of the things I am completely frightened about is performing dangerous SQL commands like `delete from x` whilst connected to my work's remote server erroneously (thinking it is my development machine). The question then is, is there a way to configure workbench to prevent you from making stupid (and usually tired) mistakes, or is there an alternative that does? Or is it just a thing of being more controlled?

Comment: `Edit > Preferences > SQL Queries > [x] Safe Updates` can help to some extent. It requires at least a `WHERE` clause on updates and deletes.

Comment: What exactly would your ideal preference for this do?

Comment: @philipolson Ideally, it would be great for the client to ask confirmation before running unsafe queries

Comment: Defining "unsafe" is the difficult part, but the aforementioned "Safe Updates" preference might do what you want.

Comment: @philipolson Thanks for your response, but the safe updates option is just not good enough

Comment: Could you submit a feature request that also includes how you would define "unsafe"?

Comment: @philipolson On the workbench site? Will do

Answer (score 0):

Getting a confirmation from the user as suggested in the comments is probably not a good solution, depending on the frequency you send queries. After the first 20-30 of such confirmation dialogs you get tired of them and just click them away.

A much better way is to establish 2 simple habits:

1. Give your users only the absolute minimum of privileges, so that they can do their work. This limits the damage they can cause.
2. Make backups. There's no question **if** you need a backup, only **when**.